# My appimage app icons are all the same

Tags: icons, appimage

All my `appimage` apps have the same icon. It's not the default `appimage` icon, it's from another app. When I download it's still the same icon.

edit: After testing on a fresh install of kde neon the comments seem to be correct, all get the default icon. However I still am sure I saw different icons for each different app. So I'm a little confused how I made that work. Either way somehow all appimages get the default icon from a random app which you can see in my image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVR1g.png)

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be nice.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Appimages, by default, are not integrated in the system. You can manually create desktop launchers and provide an icon, although nowadays, there are tools that can do this automatically

Comment: The icon from a random app is applied to all appimage apps on my system. Thats not expected behavior.

Comment: Unlike what you believe, it *is* expected behavior. In order to have the application specific icon, you must manually install an icon and a `.desktop` launcher. Nowadays, tools exist that can do that automatically.

Comment: I'd agree with you if its some default icon. But all my apps have the same icon from that one app I use. That simply is not how it worked before. I saw different icons on different appimages.